# Debugging Convert.ChangeType without source code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, syncfusion

I am using a vendor (Syncfusion) grid which is attempting to convert types but failing on an

> InvalidCastException: "Object must implement IConvertible"

Is there a way (and if so, how) to find out which type the grid is internally trying to convert to which other type?  Other than requesting support from the vendor, of course, which I am hoping to avoid unless I have to.

Comment: My first idea is stack trace. Could you provide one? Don't it show function name that suggests conversion kind?

Comment: Narrow it down from your side. What types are you throwing at the grid? BCL primitives (int, long, double, etc.) will support the interface, string is fine, but other types (including your custom types) would not.

Comment: @SergGr Sorry the stacktrace makes no mention of what type is to be converted.  Good idea though :)

Comment: @Anthony Pegram -- just nullable ints I am pretty sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug the classes of the .NET Framework by installing the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: You can also set Visual Studio to stop on every thrown exception (even on caught) and analyze local variables to see what value is converted. You will not see to what type it is converted, but probably you will see from what type